# matplotlib - pandas - How to create multiple-labels in one plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn

df = pd.read_csv(r"XXXXXXX.txt")

df.plot(x='qPkw', y='vPkw', kind='scatter', figsize=(12, 12), use_index=True,
        title="q-v-Diagram (Pkw)", xticks=[0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125], yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
        xlabel="v-Pkw", ylabel="q-Pkw", fontsize=15, color="black", label="Pkw")

df.plot(x='qLkw', y='vLkw', kind = 'scatter', figsize=(12, 12), use_index=True,
        title="q-v-Diagram (Lkw)", xticks=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30], yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
        xlabel="v-Lkw", ylabel="q-Lkw", fontsize= 15, color="blue", label="Lkw")

plt.show()
```

Instead of one, I get two plots.

I just want to have these two in one plot.
Also I want to label these two.

Someone sees the mistake?

Comment: How do you want to "label these two" if you want them in one plot? What do you mean by one plot? One set of axes, or two subfigures directly above each other?

Comment: I just want to have one "picture", but it should be clear which datas belongs to the color. The answer I got from you (below) is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the first axis, and use the `ax` keyword in the second plot with the first axis.

```
ax = df.plot(x='qPkw', y='vPkw', kind='scatter', figsize=(12, 12), use_index=True,
        title="q-v-Diagram (Pkw)", xticks=[0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125], yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
        xlabel="v-Pkw", ylabel="q-Pkw", fontsize=15, color="black", label="Pkw")

df.plot(x='qLkw', y='vLkw', kind = 'scatter', figsize=(12, 12), use_index=True,
        title="q-v-Diagram (Lkw)", xticks=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30], yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
        xlabel="v-Lkw", ylabel="q-Lkw", fontsize= 15, color="blue", label="Lkw", 
        ax=ax)
```

Be aware that the first xticks and yticks settings will be ignored. The same for the xlabel and ylabel. That has to be, since it is in one figure.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks a lot!